# Array dynamically allocated by file size is too large

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, dynamic, file-io

I am working on a class assignment and need some help with dynamically allocated arrays. I am using file_size to try to pull the file size from 3 files to allocate the array to that size, then I need to write and sort the data in the array. My issue right now is with sizing of the array; right now my output (ignoring sorting) is:

```
1
3
7
9
0
0
0
0
2
4
8
0
0
0
5
6
10
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

As you can see it is being padded with extra 0s. Here are the input files:

inputFile1:

```
1
3
7
9
```

inputFile2:

```
2
4
8
```

inputFile3:

```
5
6
10
0
```

I need some help figuring out what's going on with this and where the issue is. I want to get rid of those extra 0s, and I'm not even sure where they are coming from. Help with the sorting would also be appreciated.

file_size:

```
long file_size(FILE *inputFile)
{
    if(inputFile == NULL)
        return -1;

    long pos = ftell(inputFile);

    fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END);

    long size = ftell(inputFile);

    fseek(inputFile, pos, SEEK_SET);

    return size;    
}
```

Main:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *file0 = fopen("list0.txt", "r");
    FILE *file1 = fopen("list1.txt", "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("list2.txt", "r");
    FILE *output = fopen("hw3.out", "w");

    long size0 = file_size(file0);
    long size1 = file_size(file1);
    long size2 = file_size(file2);

    long totalSize = size0 + size1 + size2;

    int *numbers = malloc(totalSize * sizeof(int));

    int i;
    int index = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < file_size(file0); i++)
    {
        if(!feof(file0))
        {
            fscanf(file0, "%i", &numbers[index]);
            index++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < file_size(file1); i++)
    {
        if(!feof(file1))
        {
            fscanf(file1, "%i", &numbers[index]);
            index++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < file_size(file2); i++)
    {
        if(!feof(file2))
        {
            fscanf(file2, "%i", &numbers[index]);
            index++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }



    for(i = 0; i < totalSize; i++)
    {
        fprintf(output, "%i\n", numbers[i]);
    }


    fclose(file0);
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(output);
    free(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: unrelated, but you already capture the file sizes once with your function,, really no need to call that function again for each loop, just use `size0`, `size1`, and `size2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input files have several lines, each of which has the textual representation of a number.   Your file size function however is counting the total number of *bytes* in the file.  These are not the same.

While you can still use the file size to allocate space (you'll just get more than you need), you need to instead check the return value of `scanf` to see if a number was read.  If not, you jump out of the loop.

```
int index = 0;
while (fscanf(file0, "%i", &numbers[index]) == 1) {
    index++;
}
while (fscanf(file1, "%i", &numbers[index]) == 1) {
    index++;
}
while (fscanf(file2, "%i", &numbers[index]) == 1) {
    index++;
}

for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
    fprintf(output, "%i\n", numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, I had a suspicion it was reading in characters other than just the numbers. I'll give this a shot, thanks.

Comment: @cnh995 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: I ended up doing something slightly different, but this was a big help in getting me there, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The size calculation includes the carriage return "\n" character at the end of the file. Therefore, you are allocating space for 8 integers for the first file, 6 integers for the second file and 10 integers for the third file (10, because the number "10" has two digits).

The correct allocation strategy would be not to count the bytes in the files, but the lines (which actually contain numbers, thus allowing you to skip empty lines).

But that's just too much trouble. Instead, consider just allocating 1000 bytes, read in until you run out, then re-alloc into a larger buffer.